# Another Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, json

I'm pulling my hair out on this. I can write into a database with the same code (expect it's the INSERT INTO command) but this doesn't work.

**PHP:**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
//$id = '000000000002';
$uri = $_POST['uri'];
//$uri='sdfgdsfg';
try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE USERS SET PHOTO=? WHERE ID=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($uri, $id));
    $response["success"] = 1;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response["success"] = 0;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

**JAVA:**

```
try {
                        paramsC = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        paramsC.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", userid));
                        paramsC.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uri", "hello"));

                        JSONParser jsonParser; jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(set_profile_photo_uri, "POST", paramsC);

                        try {
                            int success = json.getInt("success"); //error points to this line
                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully updated
                                Log.d("SIGNUP", "success");
                            } else {
                                Log.d("SIGNUP", "fail");
                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            //Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                            //Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was:\n");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I get an error:

```
02-17 21:37:45.104: E/JSON Parser(21276): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-17 21:37:45.104: W/System.err(21276): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 21:37:45.124: W/System.err(21276):    at com.example.myapp.TabFragment1$8.onClick(TabFragment1.java:171)
```

**However, this code works, but WHY?:**

```
try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS (USERNAME, PASSWORD, NAME, EMAIL, GENDER, DATEOFREG_PHONE, DATEOFREG_SV) VALUES
        (:username, :password, :name, :email, :gender, :dateofreg_phone, :dateofreg_sv)");
            $query_params = array( 
                ':username' => $username,
                ':password' => $password,
                ':name' => $name,
                ':email' => $email,
                ':gender' => $gender,
                ':dateofreg_phone' => $dateofreg_phone,
                ':dateofreg_sv' => $dateofreg_sv
            );  
        $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        $response["success"] = 1;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

The PHP code works fine when I enter it into the browser.

Comment: I would look at what my HTTP response contains.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse HTML as JSON. Surprise, HTML is not JSON.

Comment: I don't have HTML in my code at all

Comment: Your server is responding with HTML page instead of JSON. <!DOCTYPE is a part of HTML page header.

Comment: Just look at your error message...

Comment: Maybe you query a wrong url?

Comment: I don't see any differences with the working php and java code blocks and failing ones.

Comment: I see that the SQL in both cases have nothing in common other than the table name. Are PHOTO and ID correct fields? Have you checked if you're getting an error back (because you're echoing something if there's an error, and then you don't get JSON back) ; you can try writing to an error_log, rather than echoing the error-message

Comment: @towr: Both are correct fields. If I run the php file in the browser and specify the values of the variables there it updates the table

Comment: @nikis: I checked it many times. And I still missed a character. Aaaargh, 2 hours wasted!

Comment: @erdomester Human factor, everybody makes stupid mistakes which makes cry =)

Answer (score 1):

Making an answer from comments to close this question: Make sure you send a query to a right URL.